# GCP VMWare engine- connection to Vsphere Client is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vmware

After creating a private cloud using Google Cloud VMware Engine, I can't login to the Vsphere Client, the browser shows '''ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED'''.
the following steps I performed
1 enable the ports mentioned in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine/docs/quickstart-prerequisites

2 Remove the antivirus.

But the problem still persist

Comment: From where are you trying to connect specifically (a GCE VM perhaps) ?, What is the DNS configuration you are using on that machine ?, can you provide a GCP Firewall screenshot of your [rules](https://cloud.google.com/vmware-engine/docs/quickstart-prerequisites#firewall-port-requirements) ?, are you able to use the direct internal IP address instead of the DNS name ?, are you using a customer DNS server or GCP DNS zone ?

Comment: Thank you! I looking that, maybe I forgot to provide a secure way to publish the VM.